# Как передать настройки БД в php скрипт?

Tags: jquery, post, php

Наверно не очень понятный вопрос...

Есть форма регистрации. Прикручена система валидации вводимых данных(jQuery и php).
Когда с поля ввода убирается фокус (.blur), текст из поля передается POST'ом в php скрипт расположенный в другой папке. Если нужно просто посчитать количество символов в имени, например, то все ОК. А если нужно проверить существование имени в БД, приходится в начале скрипта писать все настройки (mysql_connect... mysql_select_db...). Но таких скриптов несколько. И есть отдельно файл db.php с настройками БД.
Через includ/require файл db.php не хочеет подключаться. Передавать через java-script не хочется, т.к. видно любому, кто захочет посмотреть...

Может кто ,чего посоветовать?

UDP

Путь может быть и не правильно. Структура такая:

```
forma.php
db.php 
scripts/script.js
php/valid.php
```

В form.php подключается script.js, который отсылает данные в valid.php. Чтобы подключить db.php в valid.php нужно писать require".../db.php"?

Java:
    $("#name").blur(function()
       {
            var searchString    = $("#name").val();
            var data            = 'name='+ searchString;

```
        if(searchString) 
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "funk/check.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(html) { 
                    $("#rName").html("<img src='imgs/iLOAD.gif' width='24px' height='24px'/>"); 
               },
               success: function(html){ 
                    $("#rName").empty();
                    $("#rName").show();
                    $("#rName").append(html);
              }
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаю вопрос и думаю "сказка какая-то". Очень странно, что require у Вас не работает. может пути неверно указаны?? 
Добавлю вопрос в избранное, дабы посмотреть что за проблемы за такие о_О

Comment: Ненавижу заморочки. Олег, используйте абсолютные пути и не будет никаких проблем. Но вообще по описанию, вроде как require "../db.php";

Comment: хм... теперь просто зависает. Т.е ошибок не пишет, но и результат не выдает...

Comment: ложись спать)) утро вечера...=)

Answer (score 0):

напишите require_once '.'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'db.php';

Comment: То же самое. Java-script останавливается (зависает?) на строке  beforeSend.

Comment: код в студию

Comment: data походу не правильно оформлена)
пример заполнения ключ: значение
oem: $("#d_oem").val()

Comment: beforeSend(XMLHttpRequest):  Опция позволяет установить функцию, для модифицкации объекта XMLHttpRequest до того как он будет отправлен. Данная опция является ajax событием, поэтому для отмены отправки запроса Вам необходимо вернуть false из функции. 
Возвращаемый тип: функция.
У вас содержание данной функции не тут должно быть скорее всего

Comment: Ммм... Я думаю, дело не в java, т.к. если в php файле поставить настройки бд, все работает, а если includ'ить то нет...

Comment: Попробуйте напрямуюу запустить ваш php скрипт - и посмотерть какие ошибки выдает - не забудте поставить вывод всех ошибок